# WPF Navigation Removes Prior Pages

Tags: c#, wpf

All!  I am working on a WPF application that requires a Menu and Frame.  I am using Frame.Navigate, however, if I have 3 or 4 pages open, and I use the back button to go back to the first Page, and then add a new Page, it removes all Pages from the Navigation that were entered forward within the stack.  If this is how the Navigate/Menu feature works, how can I add a new Page when navigating anywhere within the Pages without it closing those Pages that reside in front of the new Page?  Thanks in advance!

---

Absolutely!  I have a Frame in the XAML

XAML:

```
    <Menu x:Name="mnu" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FF0062A0" Foreground="#E2E2E2" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold">
                <MenuItem Header="_Browse">
                    <MenuItem.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect/>
                    </MenuItem.Effect>
                    <MenuItem Foreground="Black" Header="Page1" Name="Page1" Click="Page1_Click"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Foreground="Black" Header="Page2" Name="Page2" Click="Page2_Click"></MenuItem>
<MenuItem Foreground="Black" Header="Page3" Name="Page3" Click="Page3_Click"></MenuItem>
<MenuItem Foreground="Black" Header="Page4" Name="Page4" Click="Page4_Click"></MenuItem>

<Frame Name="mainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" ></Frame>
```

CODE BEHIND:  Page1 loads when the application launches.  Each Page Click event is setup like this

```
private void Page1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());
        }
private void Page..._Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page...());
            }
```

An example of what the issue is:  If I open Page1, Page3, Page4, and then click the Frame's back button back to Page 1.  At this point I open Page2.  When I do this, every Page ahead on the Frame's (mainFrame) Navigation are closed (Page3 and Page4).  I need to be able to Navigate to any screen (anywhere in the Navigation stack) without closing other Pages.

Comment: The solution is quite simple. Just use long lived instances of pages instead of `new Page1()`. You can either have a locator pattern with static properties, or setup a container and register pages as lazy singletones

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using the old instances rather then new Page1(), however it still removes all Pages ahead of it in the stack when opening a new page.  I can open Page1, Page3, Page4, but then I navigate back to Page 1 and try to Navigate to Page 2, Page3 and Page4 are still removed.  Below is how i am getting to this issue:

```
1 - mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());
2 - mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page3());
3 - mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page4());
```

4 - Navigate back to Page1 using the Back button
5 - Now I call mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page2());, which then removes the Page3 and Page4